# How can I access Dart functions/variables from the Dartium DevTool Console?

Tags: dart, google-chrome-devtools, dartium

In JavaScript you can access global variables and functions from the DevTool console (e.g. to call a function manually).

I tried to do this in Dartium, but I always get a reference error.

I tried following variations:

```
testFunc () {
    return "test";
}

var testFunc2 = () {
    return "test";
}

void main() {
    var testFunc3 () {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

but none can be called via DevTool console of Dartium.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to select a Dart context.
When you open devtools > Console tab there is `<top frame>` selected by default.
You need to switch to a Dart context like `dart:core`.
As far as I remember it doesn't matter which Dart context is selected, just one of the Dart contexts.

[image]

Comment: That helped, thank you! Though I have to select the right File as the context if I want to call own functions, otherwise there will be thrown an exception.